# How to get SQL insert and/or update to not lock entire table on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, locking

Very much a newbie on DB work, so appreciate your patience with a basic question.  I'm running SQL Server 2014 on my local machine, and I have a small table and a basic client application to test different approaches with.  I'm getting what appears to be a table lock during both `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` statements.  The client is an ASP.NET application with the following code:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLNCLI11; server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=<my db>; user id=<my uid>; password=<my pwd>");
cn.Open();
OleDbTransaction tn = cn.BeginTransaction();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO LAYOUTSv2 (LAYOUTS_name_t, LAYOUTS_enabled_b, LAYOUTS_data_m) VALUES ('name', '-1', 'data')", cn, tn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int newkey = Decimal.ToInt32((decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Console.WriteLine("Created index " + newkey);
Thread.Sleep(15000);
tn.Commit();
tn = cn.BeginTransaction();
cmd.CommandText = "UDPATE LAYOUTSv2 SET LAYOUTS_enabled_b='-3' WHERE LAYOUTS_key='" + newkey + "'";
cmd.Transaction = tn;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine("updated row");
Thread.Sleep(15000);
tn.Rollback();
cn.Close();
```

I run this code, then from the management studio I run `SELECT * FROM LAYOUTSv2`.  During both cases when the client thread is paused (i.e. prior to commit/rollback) the SELECT query hangs until the commit/rollback occurs.

The table has field LAYOUTS_key assigned as the primary key.  In the properties window it shows that it is unique and clustered, with page locks and row locks both allowed.  The lock escalation setting for the table is Disable...I've tried both the other available settings of Table and AUTO with no changes.  I've tried `SELECT ... WITH (NOLOCK)` and that returns a result immediately, but as is well-cautioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx) and other places it's not what I should be doing.  I've tried putting the `ROWLOCK` hint on both the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, but nothing has changed.

The behavior I'm looking for is this:  prior to commit of an `INSERT`, queries from other threads read all rows except the one that's being `INSERT`ed.  Prior to commit of an `UPDATE` queries from other threads read the starting version of the row being `UPDATE`ed.  Is there any way I can do this?  If I need to provide other information to clarify my use case please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: By the way `WHERE LAYOUTS_key='" + newkey + "'` is a complete no-no for various reasons including SQL injection, you should use parameterised queries.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the heads-up on this...never heard of either parameterized queries or SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @JohnRiehl, re: injection attacks, imagine if your user sets `newkey` to "`something';DELETE FROM LAYOUTSv2 --`". Your update would complete successfully, and then empty the table because the user manipulated the query by inserting an apostrophe. Normally, a parameterized query looks something like `UDPATE LAYOUTSv2 SET LAYOUTS_enabled_b='-3' WHERE LAYOUTS_key=?`, after which you separately assign value(s) to the `?` (the parameter) in your code.

Comment: Wow, `OleDbConnection`, I literally haven't seen that since 2005... -- I know it's off topic -- but point of advice for new .NET developers, please check out `Entity Framework` and watch the 10 minute training videos -- and learn LINQ if you don't already know it. -- To avoid Row Locking in EF, you'll want to take a look at the `Timestamp` attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations (Not a jab at anyone, just a helpful nudge in the right direction if you find yourself here.) 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chances are it isn't locking the "whole table".

It is locking a row in the table but your `SELECT * FROM LAYOUTSv2` tries to read the whole table so necessarily is blocked by that lock.

For the insert case you can merely specify the `READPAST` hint to skip past the locked row- however that will not give your desired result for the `UPDATE` case (it will skip the row again not read the starting version of the row).

If you configure the database for [read committed snapshot isolation](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) this will give your desired effect for both cases (at the expense of greater use of `tempdb`)

Comment: I changed "Is Read Committed Snapshot On" to True and now it works perfectly with no hints needed.  Thanks!  One follow-up...I left "Allow Snapshot Isolation" set to False...is that OK?  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnRiehl - Yes if your aren't explicitly using `SNAPSHOT` isolation best to leave it disabled and then enable it if you subsequently decide this would be useful for you.

Answer (score 10):

The insert and update statements are supposed to create row-level locks. However, when the number of locks in any transaction is 5,000 or more then a lock escalation occurs and it creates a table level lock. Please see below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Not relevant to this question as both the INSERT and UPDATE statements are writing a single row